# android how to not include google-play-services.jar in my App

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

The jar file makes my Apps too fat I want to support older devices 2.3.x some basic App is now at least 4M, I cannot find a post where somebody said you don't need to include the jar file and if the file is not available ask the user the install/download it. How is this done if at all??

I used proguard and also manually deleted items off the jar file my App don't need still too big compared to the before size.

Comment: Do you use Google Play Services?

Comment: Agreed. If you don't want to use the JAR, don't use Google Play Services. This has the side benefit of opening your app up to other devices that do not support Google Play Services in the first place (Amazon Kindle Fire series, Blackberry BB10 devices, etc.).

Comment: yep you need it for Ads and maps.

Comment: @becker so you answered you own question?

Comment: My question is how to generate the apk without the jar file in it (My apps do need it) and somehow ask the user to install it.(e.g install google play from the store)

Comment: @becker you cannot do that nor does it make any sense, how would you use any code in another apk file?

Comment: Do note however that as of today if you are using Android Studio and Gradle, you can selectively include only the parts of Google Play Services that you need. See: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: @tyczj I read carefully the docs it seems like it is not possible as it needs a lib client which is the fatty jar that gets into the App. Lately I see my Apps have a large decrease in downloads but it seems like the google play services download from the store is not going too well look at the current reviews, people are fuming,  probably it is good to just step out for a while and see if Google can get their act together I'm having all kinds of issues trying to reinstall the google Play Services App on a 2.3.x device.

Comment: @becker people are fuming because they bought cheap phones with very small internal memory. The fact of the matter is google is not going to stray from google play services anytime soon because it removes the phone carries out of the equation for providing updates. so your best bet is to finally move to android studio and only import what part of google play services you need from version 6.5

Comment: Look carefully at the comments I don't think nexus7, notes3 and the like are cheapo phones. I'll take a look at the Studio and see how it goes